# LINKEDIN API - How to get user info

Tags: javascript, api, web-scraping, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I want to get user information from LinkedIn with an official API, but I can't find any endpoint that could give me such info.

something like this:

```js
fetch("https://<URL>/api/<USERNAME>")
```

is it even possible to fetch user info like this?

ideally, it would work in **browser environment**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review the [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog) to determine what, if anything, best fits your needs. It sounds like you're looking for the [Profile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api), which requires special approval to use.